# What are leísmo, loísmo, and laísmo?

Tags: pronombres, terminología, laísmo-leísmo-loísmo

What are *leísmo*, *loísmo*, and *laísmo*? How common are they, and where are they primarily encountered?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lo%C3%ADsmo and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le%C3%ADsmo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yo soy de Madrid y tengo laísmo, leísmo y loísmo cuando hablo, pero si lo pienso (al escribir) suelo darme cuenta y lo corrijo. El laísmo, leísmo y loísmo está tan arraigado en Castilla que yo no me enteré que era laísta, leísta y loísta hasta que tuve 20 años.

**Correcto**:

- Objeto directo masculino o neutro: siempre "lo"
- Objeto directo femenino: siempre "la"
- Objeto indirecto: siempre "le"

En Madrid, Castilla-León, y algunas otras zonas próximas nos equivocamos pues usamos otras reglas diferentes:

**Incorrecto**:

- Pronombre que reemplaza una palabra en femenino, siempre usamos "la". Acertamos cuando es objeto directo y cometemos laísmo cuando es objeto indirecto.
- Pronombre que reemplaza a una palabra neutra o a una cosa masculina (camino, libro, etc) siempre usamos "lo". Acertamos cuando es objeto directo y cometemos loísmo cuando es objeto indirecto.
- Pronombre que reemplaza a un ser vivo masculina, siempre usamos "le". Acertamos cuando es objeto indirecto y cometemos leísmo cuando es objeto directo.

**Formas alternativas permitidas por la RAE** que también usamos en Madrid, Castilla-León y zonas próximas:

- Pronombre que reemplaza a un HOMBRE (persona del sexo masculino). En Castilla SIEMPRE usamos "le", acertamos cuando es indirecto y la RAE acepta que lo usemos cuando es objeto directo. «Yo maté al gato» y «Yo maté a José», lo correcto es decir «yo lo maté», pero en Castilla y Madrid diferenciamos «yo lo maté» (al gato) y «yo le maté» (a José) y la RAE nos lo permite.

Ejemplo de laísmo:

> Yo dije hola a mi madre

- Correcto: «yo le dije hola» pues "le" reemplaza al objeto indirecto.
- Incorrecto: «yo la dije hola» basándonos erróneamente en que mi madre es una mujer. El pronombre reemplaza al objeto indirecto y por ello lo correcto es "le" siendo irrelevante si es masculino o femenino.

Ejemplo de leísmo

> Yo pegué con pegamento el adhesivo de Superman en la puerta

- Correcto: «yo lo pegué en la puerta» pues "lo" reemplaza al objeto directo.
- Incorrecto: «yo le pegué en la puerta»

Ejemplo de uso permitido por la RAE del "le" como objeto directo:

> Yo pegué con pegamento a Superman en la puerta

- Correcto: «yo lo pegué en la puerta» pues "lo" reemplaza al objeto directo.
- Permitido: «yo le pegué en la puerta» pues "le" reemplaza a un varón.

Ejemplo de loísmo

> Yo pegué un puñetazo a Superman

- Correcto: «yo le pegué» pues "le" reemplaza al objeto indirecto (a Superman).
- Incorrecto: «yo lo pegué»

Como curiosidad, observa que ciertas expresiones como «yo lo pegué» o «yo la dije» cambian se significado dependiendo de si quien lo oye es loísta/laísta o no. Cuando decimos «yo lo pegué», lo correcto es entender que algo fue pegado con pegamento mientras que un loísta entenderá que alguien fue golpeado. Y cuando decimos «yo la dije», lo correcto es entender que algo (una palabra) fue dicha mientras que un laísta entenderá que yo dije algo a una mujer.

Comment: Una respuesta muy buena y completa.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly find more in those links that Belisarius posted under your question, and probably in many other sites, but I'd like to give a quick explanation so you start understanding what they are:

- For the function of **Indirect Object**, in Spanish you should use "le" and "les".

  > *A María le he dado un libro.* (I gave Maria a book.)
- For the function of **Direct Object**, you should use "lo/los" for masculine, "la/las" for feminine.

  > *Los encontré ayer.* (I met them yesterday.)

After this introduction, you can see that these phenomena consist in "exceptions" to the rules listed abpve:

1. **Leísmo**: This term refers to the usage of "le/les" for the function of Direct Object. The Real Academia Española accepts the "leísmo" when it appears behind the impersonal "se" or when it's referred to singular masculine, for example:

   > *A Juan le vi ayer.* (I saw Juan yesterday.)
2. **Laísmo**: This one refers to the usage of "la/las" for the function of Indirect Object:

   > *La dije que viniera.* (I told her to come.)
3. **Loísmo**: This is less frequent, and it consists of the usage of "lo/los" for the function of Indirect Object

   > *Lo entregué la carta a Luis.* (I sent the letter to Luis.)