# Mucho gusto en/de conocerlo?

Tags: saludos

Is it correct to use "(mucho) gusto en conocerlo" for a formal greeting?

My question is about the "lo", it sounds like the neutral "lo", a bit like the English pronoun "it". Isn't it the case?
I would rather use "conocerle", that seems more logical to me.

I've found that in Spanish forums, so I want to know if it's 100% a mistake, or if it's used in some areas. If it's a mistake, is it very common?

As a bonus, I suppose that both "en" and "de" could be used, isn't it?

Thank you.

Comment: No. It is correct. The ending (pronoun) implies the subject depending on gender and number: conocerlo (a el/a usted masc.) conocerla (a ella/a usted fem.) conocerle (a el /a ella/a ud more common in Spain than in Latam.) conocerlos (a ellos/a ustedes), etc

Comment: Thank you. Could you turn it into an answer please? That's a question/answer that could be interesting for a lot of people wondering the same. I always though that "lo" would be neutral, I always read that in grammar books.

Comment: I'm made a comment to help you solve this quickly but I did not make it an answer because I think this has been answered before. I have not been able to find that answer yet but I guess soon someone will mark this a as a duplicate :-)

Comment: Related question: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/670/11102

Comment: The lo/le thing has always driven me nuts.  I think that your instinct to use "le" comes from the idea that "le" is for people and "lo" is for things -- which is an oversimplification.  I personally agree with @wimi's answer, but there is another Q-A about this here on the site, where "le" is recommended by a prestigious user. My conclusion: it's a regional thing.  In what country would you like to use this phrase, may I ask?

Comment: @aparente001 RAE [now officially also accepts](https://www.rae.es/consultas/uso-de-los-pronombres-los-las-les-leismo-laismo-loismo) the use of *le* as a direct object when the direct object is a man (RAE's word, meaning "masculine person"). So "Encantado the conocerle" is also fine. But *lo* is what is originally correct, and what I defend because I am kind of a purist... I will update my answer though.

Comment: @wimi - Would you care to make an entry for yourself at Quiénes Somos?  https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2586/9385  I'm just curious, because Diego, who wrote the other answer with the "le," is from Spain.

Comment: @aparente001 done, though I did not add much information there, as I do not want to give too much [PII](https://www.lifelock.com/learn-identity-theft-resources-what-is-personally-identifiable-information.html). Yes, I come from an area with leísmo, maybe that is why I learned to go against it...

Comment: @wimi - Thanks.  It's always nice to know about someone's languages and regional influences. // That's so interesting that growing up in a leísmo region actually *led* you to consciously avoid it. // Are you sure you don't want to briefly mention the regional factor in your answer?

Answer (score 2):

"Conocerlo" is correct because "lo/la" is used for direct objects, while "le" is used for indirect objects. See [here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/670/24236) for more information. The verb "conocer" is transitive and takes a direct object, so it requires "lo" or "la".

However, the use of *le* for a direct object when the direct object is a man (masculine person) is so widespread that it has also been [accepted by RAE](https://www.rae.es/consultas/uso-de-los-pronombres-los-las-les-leismo-laismo-loismo). This means that "Mucho gusto de conocerlo" and "Mucho gusto de conocerle" are both fine if referring to a man, but one must say "Mucho gusto de conocerla" for women.

I would not use "en" in that sentence, I think only "Mucho gusto de conocerlo" is correct. Another option is to say "Mucho gusto" alone.

Comment: I like your explanation of the object pronoun.  I'm not so wild about your second paragraph, though.  Prepositions can be so squishy.

Comment: @aparente001 which preposition would you use in this case? Honestly, I am used to "Encantado de conocerlo", and no preposition sounds good to me with "Mucho gusto ___ conocerlo", though "de" sounds less bad than "en"...

Comment: Thanks for adding the "le" variant.  Maybe this is a regional thing and you might want to add that.  I get soo confused about the whole lo/le issue that you should not blindly follow any suggestion from me about that topic, though. // I'm used to hearing "de" but I have the impression it's okay to say "en."  Maybe next week others will start to chime in.