# Explanation for "Ellos no le habian invitado a Ana a cenar pero ella vino igual"

Tags: traducción

In my Duolingo app, the mentioned translation isn't preferred, instead **"No habian invitado a Ana a cenar, pero vino igual"** is the prevalent one.

I want to know whether "le" is omitted because it is incorrect or because it is redundant, given "a Ana" already clarifies the person being referred to.

Comment: Note that usually subject pronouns are dropped unless there is ambiguity which is what Duolingo has done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence

> Ellos no le habían invitado a Ana a cenar pero ella vino igual

is grammatically **incorrect**, because "a Ana" is a **direct object**, so it can be replaced/referred to by the pronoun "la", but not by the pronoun "le". This kind of mistake is called "leísmo". See [here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/670/24236) for the rules on "lo", "la", and "le".

Indirect objects [can be redundantly referred to](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32243/24236) by both a noun and the pronoun "le/les", so the sentence

- Ellos no **le** preguntaron **a Ana** si quería venir

is correct. However, in most of the Spanish-speaking world, direct objects cannot be redundantly referred to by "lo/la/los/las" if the other instance is a noun that appears after the verb (see paragraph 5.2b [here](https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos)). Therefore, the following two sentences are correct:

- Ellos habian invitado **a Ana** a cenar, pero vino igual
- Ellos no **la** habian invitado a cenar, pero vino igual

but the following sentence is incorrect in most regions:

- Ellos **la** habian invitado **a Ana** a cenar, pero vino igual.

As also mentioned in paragraph 5.2 of the [linked DPD article](https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos), this last sentence is correct in a few Spanish-speaking regions, particularly the countries around *Río de la Plata* (Argentina, Uruguay).

Comment: I'd clarify that the last sentence is incorrect in most but not all of the Spanish-speaking world, In my country, the last sentence is perfect: "La duplicación del complemento directo en otros casos (Lo vi a Juan; La saludé a María) es ajena a la norma culta de gran parte del ámbito hispánico, pero es normal en algunas regiones americanas, especialmente en los países del Río de la Plata: «Al pasar la madre cerca del baño la vio a Mariana tomando comprimidos» (Rausch/Bay Anorexia [Arg. 1990])."

Comment: @Gustavson done. I clearly should have read the complete paragraph before writing the answer ;)

Comment: Interesting that you dropped the _ellos_ part way through without comment. Is it worth pointing out why to the OP although to be fair that was not their specific question?

Comment: @mdewey I guess I dropped it instinctively because that is how I am used to speaking... I just added it back, to avoid adding yet another topic to the answer.